# Google cloud function deployment vs runtime permissions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permissions, serverless

I am paranoid about security and this makes no sense to me. I must be missing something here. I can get it working no problems. But I want to know why? What is the philosophy behind it? and how am I protected?

I wrote a google cloud function that receives a post request and publishes an event to a google pubsub topic. I've set up my topic pubsub resource and set up an iam binding so that only my functions service account can publish to that channel - that is all good.

However, it does not let me deploy (using gcloud functions deploy --service-account=...) my function with that service account. Says it does not have secretAccessor and and deploymentManager.editor and cloudfunctions.developer etc

My confusion is...why should it need development/deployment related permissions? I am deploying the function and I have those permissions. So it should use my permissions to deploy. But when the function is actually running, I dont want it to have those development/deployment management permissions in case there is some vulnerability that can be exploited. I want it to run as the service account I specify. It needs to be restricted to only the permissions related to receiving request and publishing to my topic. Otherwise it would break the principle of having least privileges.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a service such as Functions, Run, or Compute Engine, you, as the deployer, need two types of permissions:

- Permission to create the service
- Permission to assign an existing identity (aka service account) to the service.

The service typically needs an identity (service account) with appropriate permissions. The permissions are the ones required for the service to access other services and resources. This service runs independently of the identity that created the service.

Two identities and two sets of permissions to manage. That means your goal of least privilege can be achieved.

> My confusion is...why should it need development/deployment related
> permissions?

I do not know because your question does not have the details required to answer. The error you posted does not make sense in the context described. I am not aware of any instance where, for example, deploying a Function requires **Deployment Manager Editor** for the Function's identity. The function itself might need that IAM role, but the deployment command does not nor does the deployment command even know which permissions the function requires except for those derived by the command line flags.

If you need more help on this, edit your question to clearly describe both identities and IAM roles, the deployment, which resources are accessed, and how you are deploying. Include the actual commands and error messages.